# While building a NextJS Application in Nx workspace - getting error :Cannot find module 'typescript'

Tags: typescript, next.js, nrwl-nx, nrwl

While creating a new @nrwl/workspace with a next JS app - i get error
Error: Cannot find module 'typescript'. Anyone encountering the same issue ?

Steps -

1. Create a new nx workspace
2. Create a new App with NextJS Preset
3. Build the app with `nx run <app-name>:build`
4. Generate image from `dist/apps/<app-name>` or just copy the dist somewhere
5. run `yarn` or `npm install`
6. After modules are installed - start the application with `yarn start`

error which comes

```
Error: Cannot find module 'typescript'
Require stack:
- E:\projects\rainn\pocs\sample-one\node_modules\@nrwl\workspace\src\utilities\typescript\compilation.js
- E:\projects\rainn\pocs\sample-one\node_modules\@nrwl\workspace\src\utilities\typescript.js
- E:\projects\rainn\pocs\sample-one\node_modules\@nrwl\workspace\src\core\target-project-locator.js
- E:\projects\rainn\pocs\sample-one\node_modules\@nrwl\workspace\src\core\project-graph\build-dependencies\explicit-project-dependencies.js
- E:\projects\rainn\pocs\sample-one\node_modules\@nrwl\workspace\src\core\project-graph\build-dependencies\index.js
- E:\projects\rainn\pocs\sample-one\node_modules\@nrwl\workspace\src\core\project-graph\project-graph.js
- E:\projects\rainn\pocs\sample-one\node_modules\@nrwl\workspace\src\core\file-utils.js
- E:\projects\rainn\pocs\sample-one\node_modules\@nrwl\next\plugins\with-nx.js
- E:\projects\rainn\pocs\sample-one\next.config.js
- E:\projects\rainn\pocs\sample-one\node_modules\next\dist\server\config.js
- E:\projects\rainn\pocs\sample-one\node_modules\next\dist\server\next.js
- E:\projects\rainn\pocs\sample-one\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\start-server.js
- E:\projects\rainn\pocs\sample-one\node_modules\next\dist\cli\next-start.js
- E:\projects\rainn\pocs\sample-one\node_modules\next\dist\bin\next
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:889:15)
    at Function.mod._resolveFilename (E:\projects\rainn\pocs\sample-one\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\require-hook.js:96:28)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\projects\rainn\pocs\sample-one\node_modules\@nrwl\workspace\src\utilities\typescript\compilation.js:7:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'E:\\projects\\rainn\\pocs\\sample-one\\node_modules\\@nrwl\\workspace\\src\\utilities\\typescript\\compilation.js',    'E:\\projects\\rainn\\pocs\\sample-one\\node_modules\\@nrwl\\workspace\\src\\utilities\\typescript.js',
    'E:\\projects\\rainn\\pocs\\sample-one\\node_modules\\@nrwl\\workspace\\src\\core\\target-project-locator.js',
    'E:\\projects\\rainn\\pocs\\sample-one\\node_modules\\@nrwl\\workspace\\src\\core\\project-graph\\build-dependencies\\explicit-project-dependencies.js',
    'E:\\projects\\rainn\\pocs\\sample-one\\node_modules\\@nrwl\\workspace\\src\\core\\project-graph\\build-dependencies\\index.js',
    'E:\\projects\\rainn\\pocs\\sample-one\\node_modules\\@nrwl\\workspace\\src\\core\\project-graph\\project-graph.js',    'E:\\projects\\rainn\\pocs\\sample-one\\node_modules\\@nrwl\\workspace\\src\\core\\file-utils.js',
    'E:\\projects\\rainn\\pocs\\sample-one\\node_modules\\@nrwl\\next\\plugins\\with-nx.js',
    'E:\\projects\\rainn\\pocs\\sample-one\\next.config.js',
    'E:\\projects\\rainn\\pocs\\sample-one\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\server\\config.js',
    'E:\\projects\\rainn\\pocs\\sample-one\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\server\\next.js',
    'E:\\projects\\rainn\\pocs\\sample-one\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\server\\lib\\start-server.js',
    'E:\\projects\\rainn\\pocs\\sample-one\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\cli\\next-start.js',
    'E:\\projects\\rainn\\pocs\\sample-one\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\bin\\next'
  ]
}
```

Versions
NextJS: 11.1.0
@nrwl/nx-workspace: 12.9.0
node:14.7.5
npm:6.14.4

Workspace.json

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "projects": {
    "sample-one": {
      "root": "apps/sample-one",
      "sourceRoot": "apps/sample-one",
      "projectType": "application",
      "targets": {
        "build": {
          "executor": "@nrwl/next:build",
          "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
          "options": {
            "root": "apps/sample-one",
            "outputPath": "dist/apps/sample-one"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {}
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "executor": "@nrwl/next:server",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "sample-one:build",
            "dev": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "sample-one:build:production",
              "dev": false
            }
          }
        },
        "export": {
          "executor": "@nrwl/next:export",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "sample-one:build:production"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "executor": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
          "outputs": ["coverage/apps/sample-one"],
          "options": {
            "jestConfig": "apps/sample-one/jest.config.js",
            "passWithNoTests": true
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "executor": "@nrwl/linter:eslint",
          "outputs": ["{options.outputFile}"],
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": ["apps/sample-one/**/*.{ts,tsx,js,jsx}"]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "sample-one-e2e": {
      "root": "apps/sample-one-e2e",
      "sourceRoot": "apps/sample-one-e2e/src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "targets": {
        "e2e": {
          "executor": "@nrwl/cypress:cypress",
          "options": {
            "cypressConfig": "apps/sample-one-e2e/cypress.json",
            "devServerTarget": "sample-one:serve",
            "tsConfig": "apps/sample-one-e2e/tsconfig.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "sample-one:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "executor": "@nrwl/linter:eslint",
          "outputs": ["{options.outputFile}"],
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": ["apps/sample-one-e2e/**/*.{js,ts}"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "defaultCollection": "@nrwl/next"
  },
  "generators": {
    "@nrwl/react": {
      "application": {
        "babel": true
      }
    },
    "@nrwl/next": {
      "application": {
        "style": "scss",
        "linter": "eslint"
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "sample-one"
}
```

Thanks & Regards,